# How to round a shadow in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a rounded UIView, which should also have a shadow. So far, everything works, but on the corners, the shadow isn't rounded properly.

How to round the shadow corner?

Here's the code and a screenshot:

```
popupView.layer.cornerRadius = 15

popupView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
popupView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
popupView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
popupView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
popupView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: popupView.bounds).cgPath
popupView.layer.shouldRasterize = false
```

[image]

Comment: Needs to be `popupView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: popupView.bounds, cornerRadius: 15.0).cgPath`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
popupView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: popupView.bounds, cornerRadius: 15).cgPath
```

instead of

```
popupView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: popupView.bounds).cgPath
```

and add a little bit of shadowOpacity like a 1.3 to see better the shadow.

Answer (score 3):

So, I basically threw your code into Playground and played around with a bit, what I found was, I could basically remove `view.layer.shadowPath` and it would work...

[image: Basically works]

```
import UIKit

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 500, height: 500))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
view.layer.cornerRadius = 15

view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
view.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
//view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds).cgPath
view.layer.shouldRasterize = false


let outter = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 700, height: 700))
outter.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
outter.addSubview(view)


outter
```

What I also found was:

- `view.layer.masksToBounds = true` did not achieve the desired result
- `view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, cornerRadius: 15).cgPath` also works, but adds in an additional point of failure, as you need to remember to set the `cornerRadius` property if you change it on the view, or add a variable to seed both, but since if you didn't set the `shadowPath`, it would generate the same result, it makes me wonder why you'd both using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the views layers masksToBounds value to true

popupView.layer.masksToBounds = true