# How to apply corner radius to certain corners and add shadow

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to apply rounded corners to certain corners only, and at the same time apply a shadow layer?

I tried doing that using the following extension, but that didn't work for me:

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, shadow: Bool = false) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
        if shadow {
            self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview), [example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-round-only-specific-corners-using-maskedcorners), [example](https://www.appcoda.com/rounded-corners-uiview/) and [shadowing rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431760/how-to-round-a-shadow-in-ios/52432975#52432975)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes I know, but they don't apply a shadow layer over their corners. The rounded corner part is working, so is the shadow part, but together, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tossed in some code into playground and had a quick playground, based on the example from [How to round only specific corners using maskedCorners](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-round-only-specific-corners-using-maskedcorners)

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 500, height: 500))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]

view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
view.layer.shadowRadius = 4
//view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds).cgPath
view.layer.shouldRasterize = false


let outter = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 700, height: 700))
outter.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
outter.addSubview(view)


outter
```

I did some testing:

With no corner radius

[image: No corner Radius]

With masked corner radius

[image: With masked corner]

With reduced `shawdowRadius`

[image: Reduced shadowRadius]

And just to be sure, increased corner radius

[image: Increased corner radius]

Comment: Ok, so I have a demonstrable example showing the concept requested - so, why the downvote?  Since there's no other answer, I assume there's no better ideas?