# Swift Shadow and corner radius not visible

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, radius

I want a view with some shadow and corner radius the problem i have when i have shadow the corner radius is not available i set masktobound to false and i have added this code

```
  func setShadow() {
    cardCBView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cardCBView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cardCBView.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8980392157, green: 0.8980392157, blue: 0.8980392157, alpha: 0)
    cardCBView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cardCBView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    cardCBView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    cardCBView.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
 }
```

i have result like image : 
with masktobound off
[image: with masktobound off]

with masktobound = on
[image: with masktobound = on]

when i put different color for bordercolor
[image: when i put different color for bordercolor]

how can i have shadow and radius corner ?

any help is appreciated

Comment: You cannot clip to the corner radius and cast a shadow from the same view. They are opposites. See my discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57351560/341994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three steps through which you can achieve both shadow and corers

1. Add one more view behind CardCB View with same frame or constraints
2. Add corners to this view ad set `clipToBounds = true`
3. Give your main view shadow and set its `clipToBounds = false`

Comment: This is correct but not new. Your duty is, rather than to repeat this info, to find a duplicate (there are many) and vote to close.

Answer (score -1):

You should set

```
clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: With this i loose shadow :( i can't see it

Comment: is `func setShadow()` used in `func layoutSubviews()`?

Comment: i put it on  layoutSubviews but still same problem i don't see shadow

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it