# In iOS, how to have view with rounded corners and drop shadow mask its subview?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, calayer

I'm trying to create something like this image except for those purple corners. Notice how the blue (shown as purple) `contentView` is not being clipped or masked by its parent `containerView`.

[image: Card view]

The requirements are to have a view which:

1. Has rounded corners.
2. Has a shadow.
3. It's subviews don't leak outside of it or its corners.

Here is the code I'm playing around with and I'm not sure exactly how to get this to work.

```swift
let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 300, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
containerView.backgroundColor = .green
containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 40
containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 50
containerView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
view.addSubview(containerView)

let backgroundLayer = CALayer()
backgroundLayer.frame = containerView.layer.bounds
backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
backgroundLayer.opacity = 0.5
backgroundLayer.cornerRadius = containerView.layer.cornerRadius
backgroundLayer.masksToBounds = true
containerView.layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)

let contentView = UIView(frame: containerView.bounds)
contentView.backgroundColor = .blue
contentView.alpha = 0.3

// Omitting this line will produce a green square with rounded corners
// and a red shadow.
containerView.addSubview(contentView)
```

Based on this example code, one of my more specific questions is why doesn't the `backgroundLayer` which sets `masksToBounds = true`, mask the view's subview?

Comment: Impossible. If it has rounded corners and clips to them, it cannot have a shadow. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57351560/341994 for a trick you can use.

Comment: I don't think that's true because if you take the example code and delete the last section or line which adds the `contentView` as a subview, you'll see a green square with rounded corners with a red shadow.

Comment: @matt I tried two views like the answer you linked and that definitely works. I was hoping to get this with a single view. I guess I don't understand why it can't happen, especially when one of the view's layer is masking to bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Based on this example code, one of my more specific questions is why doesn't the `backgroundLayer` which sets `masksToBounds = true`, mask the view's subview?

Because the subview is the subview of the view, not of the `backgroundLayer`.

Views are layers. Clipping is masking. A layer masks its own drawing and that of its sublayers. The subview's layer is *not* a sublayer of the `backgroundLayer`. It is its sibling, not its child. Your view/layer hierarchy looks like this:

```
    containerView
     |          \
  [layer]   backgroundLayer
     |         (clips itself and its sublayers,
 contentView    but it has no sublayers)
     |
  [layer]
```

Comment: Added a diagram, I think this will help.